# What really is 红尘?

Tags: vocabulary, word

What exactly are 红尘 referring to?  This two words showed up quite often in period dramas.   An explanation and examples would be great.

Comment: A detailed explanation of 红尘 can be found on the internet, you just need to enter it into a search engine.  and the first link to show up is this: https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%B4%85%E5%A1%B5/2377 In short, 红尘 refers to "the mortal (material)world" and the term was popularized by many appearances in poems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“红尘”，一般指人间俗世之意。道教，佛教指人世间 - Human Society (the world human lives, same as 凡尘).

“红尘”, in ancient terms, also mean 车马扬起的飞尘 (dust caused by the passing of the horse cartage), and 繁华之地 (a flourishing and busy place where the crowd gathers).

Comment: Is there any difference between “红尘” & "天下"?

Comment: @WayneCheah 天下 is "the land under the sky/the sun (世界) - 天下人/事物 ", also implies "territory (疆域) - 大宋 天下". 天下 is tangible. 红尘 has the meaning, 世間, which is close to 世界, but it is more of a philosophical, imaginary, world/place that is intangible (無邊無涯). Hope this explains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @WayneCheah You are welcome.